# jQuery Vallenato Accordion Display

Tags: jquery, accordion, default

This jQuery accordion script displays the first accordion content by default. How would I set the third accordion content to display by default?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

//Set The Accordion Content Width
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');


// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }

    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
});

return false;
});
```

http://www.switchroyale.com/vallenato/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete this lines:

```
//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
```

And add this:

```
$('.accordion-header:eq(2)').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content:eq(2)').slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
```

The part with `:eq(2)` defines default section